# select interrupted system call

Tags: c, linux, timer, embedded-linux

I am creating a timer which runs approximately every second and which is waiting for a key to be pressed (which i am not doing). While it is running it shows:

```
select : interrupted system call 
select : interrupted system call 
select : interrupted system call 
select : interrupted system call
```

Can you tell me why its this is happening:

```
struct sigaction s1;
static timer_t tid3;    
sigfillset(&s1.sa_mask);
s1.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
s1.sa_sigaction = SignalHandler;
if (sigaction(SIGU, &s1, NULL) == -1) 
{
  perror("s1 failed");
  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
printf("\nTimer %d is setting up \n",TimerIdentity);    
tid3=SetTimer(SIGU, 1000, 1);

// ---------- SET timer values -------------------
static struct sigevent sigev;
static timer_t tid;
static struct itimerspec itval;
static struct itimerspec oitval;
sigev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
sigev.sigev_signo = signo;
sigev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &tid;

if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sigev, &tid) == 0) 
{
    itval.it_value.tv_sec = sec/1000;
    itval.it_value.tv_nsec = (long)(sec % 1000) * (1000000L);
    //itval.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;

    if (mode == 1) 
    {
        itval.it_interval.tv_sec = itval.it_value.tv_sec;
        itval.it_interval.tv_nsec = itval.it_value.tv_nsec;
    }
    if (timer_settime(tid, 0, &itval, NULL) == 0) 
    {
        printf("Timer_settime \n");
    }
    else
    {
        perror("time_settime error!");
    }
}

//---------------- SIGNAL HANDLER ---------------- 

void SignalHandler(int signo, siginfo_t* info, void* context)
{
    else if (signo == SIGU) // for keypad being pressed
   {
      calltimer3function();
   }
```

}

```
//-----------------calltimer3function------------------------  

unsigned char key5_debounce=0,key5_debounce_count=0;
calltimer3function()
{
    if(!key5_debounce)
   {
       if((GPIORead(INPUT_SW5)==0))
       {
          key5_debounce=1;
       }
   }
   if(key5_debounce)
   {
       if((GPIORead(INPUT_SW5)==0))
       {
          key5_debounce_count++;
       }
       else
       key5_debounce=0;

        if(key5_debounce_count>=KEY_DEBOUNCE)
        {
           printf("key5 pressed\n");
           extr_count=1;
           printf("\nDisplay menu called");
           display_menu();

          key5_debounce=0;
          key5_debounce_count=0;
        }

   }
}
```

Comment: its very annoying.. What annoying? user experience of pressing button?

Comment: the message which is popping up                                                                signal : interrupted system call                                                                     and i am not pressing any button its empty handler for now

Comment: Please show a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You haven't even shown the declaration and setting of `sigev` and also how/where the `select` call is made. Which are highly relevant to your question.

Answer (score 4):

It may be worth mentioning two things:

1. Blocking functions such as `select`, `read`, etc.. get interrupted by signals. You may like to set `SA_RESTART` flag when calling `sigaction`. `man signal(7)`:

> If a signal handler is invoked while a system call or library function call is blocked, then either:
>
> - the call is automatically restarted after the signal handler returns; or
> - the call fails with the error EINTR.
>
> Which of these two behaviors occurs depends on the interface and whether or not the signal handler was established using the SA_RESTART flag (see sigaction(2)). The details vary across UNIX systems; below, the details for Linux.

2. In the signal handler you should only call async signal safe functions. Or use [the self-pipe trick](https://lwn.net/Articles/177897/) to avoid doing anything in the signal handler at all.

Alternatively, there is a way to have timers without using `timer_create` and `timerfd_create`. `select` accepts a timeout argument which can be used to specify time till the next timer expiry. Then, `select` returns 0 if the timeout occurred. This method applies to other event demultiplexing APIs, such as `poll` and `epoll`.

Comment: and as in code i am not using any printf or any other sync signal its just empty handler and not even perror(select ) or somthing

Comment: @vm1991 You need to post a complete example that we can run and see what you see.

Comment: code is an small part of an project and  this timer uses  only above mentioned code no other code is accessed by this timer as you can see in handler it only call calltimer3function()

Comment: @vm1991 May be you are right, but without the source code we shall never know for sure.

Comment: @ maxim  hey thanx for your response so far , i am thinking can there be a problem with SIGFILLSET should i use SIGEMPTYSET insted or sigempty before sigfill  will it provide some difference ??